# Отправить данные с помощью JSONP

Tags: angular2, typescript, angular5

Как можно реализовать на Angular2 передачу данных посредством JSONP?

У меня есть реализация на JQuery, хочу понять как это реализовать на Angular2.

```
var postdata = {
    "publicid": "7c8608adb65c8",
    "lastname": 'Петя',
    "mobile": '0000000000'
};
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    url: 'https://url/capture.php',
    data: postdata
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно оставить реализацию на JQuery, подключив пакет к своему проекту Angular2

1. добавить зависимость:
   `npm install --save jquery`
2. Импортировать
   `import * as $ from 'jquery';`
3. Cам метод:

`sendData(data) {`

```
let postData = {
  "leadsource": "",
  "publicid": "7c8608adb65c8",
  "lastname": data.value.name,
  "mobile": data.value.phone,
};`

`$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  url: 'https://url/capture.php',
  data: postData,
});
}`
```